# MSQL Wordpress: Дублирующаяся запись '0' по ключу 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Экспортировал базу mysql вордпресса, потом залил обратно. Теперь ничего нельзя добавить в таблицу postmeta, выдает: #1062 - Дублирующаяся запись '0' по ключу 'PRIMARY'

Например на этот запрос: INSERT INTO `fbi_postmeta` (`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`) VALUES ('', '0', 'test', 'test')

Если meta_id указать вручную, то нормально работает.

Насколько я понимаю, при указании meta_id = '', значение meta_id берется не с последнего значения в таблице, а с 0.

Как сделать так, чтобы бралось с последнего?

Структура таблицы: [image: Структура таблицы]

Comment: а AUTO_INCREMENT стоит у meta_id?

Comment: Нет. Я пробовал "ALTER TABLE `fbi_postmeta` AUTO_INCREMENT = 555",  но не работает

Comment: "Экспортировал базу mysql вордпресса, потом залил обратно". Зачем? Ты поломал базу. А на скрине у тебя все первичные ключи - не видишь?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_postmeta

Comment: Затем что делал бекап. С каких пор сохранение и восстановление должно базы ее ломать? По поводу всех первичных ключей - в этой таблице в других базах wordpress тоже так

Comment: Если не правильно сделать, то поломать - как 2 пальца об асфальт

Comment: Посмотри в конец таблицы - там скорее всего записи с пустым полем которое должно быть с праймериз Кеем. Удаляешься эти записи. Потом в структуре добавляет праймериз Кей. И все должно встать на места)

Comment: И вообще нечего лазить в базу ВП руками. Для всего в ВП есть АПИ. В крайнем случае [wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: SeVlad экспортировал через phpmyadmin - хз что там можно поломать в 2 клика. А вообще благодарю за очень "ценные
" рекомендации по сути вопроса

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис нет там записей с пустым полем

Comment: Нет автоинкримента.Вот и удивляйся "как можно поломать". Я не знаю, я за много лет ни разу как-то не ломал. Я только вижу результат. Не ты первый не ты последний.

Comment: @SeVlad молодец

Comment: Проверь тип ключа TINYINT или INTEGER

Comment: А что это проверка даст? И какую связь это имеет с вопросом?

Answer (score 2):

Поле `meta_id`, по которому объявлен `primary index`, само это поле должно иметь атрибут `auto_increment`

```
 `meta_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

В ином случае все добавляемые вот так `"INSERT INTO fbi_postmeta (meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ('', '0', 'test', 'test')"` записи будут получать `meta_id` равным 0 и всё сломается на добавлении второй строки.